# App Store submission - Objective-C replace Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, app-store

Some time ago I submitted an application in Swift 1.0.
Now I was asked to update that application but swift has come a long way.
So long that I've got a lot to catch up now.

My question: Is it possible to update an application on the App Store in Objective-c if the previous version was written in Swift?
Of course this is not the optimal solution but when I tried to upgrade swift to the latest version, there we so many errors that I feel more confident rewriting the whole thing from start.
App update is required because of persistent data. (a new app is not an option).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why not rewrite it in swift?

Comment: @Code 
First of all, why the down vote?
Second, like I said, which I'm sure you read " I feel more confident rewriting the whole thing from start". Obviously, if the topic is "Objective-C replace Swift", I don't feel comfortable writing in swift.
Also deadlines...

Comment: I did not down vote.

Comment: @Code ah, sorry then. I thought only people that comment get to vote... my bad

Comment: @Shak in the long run, I suggest you use Swift. Swift is only going to improve from here, whereas ObjC will stay the same or may even be removed.

Comment: @penatheboss I understand that. I'm not against swift. I just need to know if it is possible.
That's the best way for me to weight the pros and cons.
I will need to redo the whole thing from scratch anyway.

It's just that deadlines and budgets don't extend that much. Objective-C would be A LOT faster right now than redoing it while learning a new language.... not something I look forward right now...

Been there, done that with the previous version.